# mongodb.service error on startup

Tags: mongodb, raspberry-pi3, raspbian

I'm running mongodb 3.0.14 on a raspberry-pi 3 with raspbian stretch 4.9.41-v7+ (32 bits). Everything works fine except when mongodb.service have to start during the system startup. It gives me the following error message, preventing the service from starting:

> listen(): bind() failed errno:99 Cannot assign requested address for socket: 192.168.1.16:27017

My mongodb.conf archive is:

```
# /etc/mongodb.conf
# minimal config file (old style)
# Run mongod --help to see a list of options

bind_ip = 127.0.0.1,192.168.1.16
#port = 27017
quiet = true
dbpath = /data/db
logpath = /data/log/mongodb.log
logappend = true
storageEngine = mmapv1
```

And my mongodb.service archive is:

```
[Unit]
Description=High-performance, schema-free document-oriented database
After=network.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/mongod --quiet --config /etc/mongodb.conf
# (file size)
LimitFSIZE=infinity
# (cpu time)
LimitCPU=infinity
# (virtual memory size)
LimitAS=infinity
# (open files)
LimitNOFILE=64000
# (processes/threads)
LimitNPROC=64000

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I've done several tests changing the [Unit]He hecho varias pruebas modificando el [Unit], thinking that the network has not yet been initialized, with the following:

```
[Unit]
Wants=network-online.target
After=network.target network-online.target
Requires=network.target network-online.target
```

But nothing works.

Once the system has finished booting, I can manually start the service, working perfectly, without giving the above error message and being able to access mongo from any other device in my network.

Any idea what is happening in the boot?.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I guess the ip `192.168.1.16` is one your pi gets from a fritzbox or similar by DHCP. so the problem is that mongo-db tries to bind to that ip before it was assigned. you even don't need to bind it anyways. just forward the port on your router to your pi.

Comment: I agree with you. mongodb tries to bind to the ip before it was assigned. But, shouldn't mongodb wait for the network with the changes I've tried?

Answer (score 0):

Just changes the `After` attribute to `After=multi-user.target`

```
Description=High-performance, schema-free document-oriented database
After=multi-user.target

[Service]
User=mongodb
ExecStart=/usr/bin/mongod --quiet --config /etc/mongodb.conf

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

After this changes, do:

```
$ systemctl daemon-reload

$ systemctl enable mongodb.service
```

It likely will run `mongodb` very later.